# How to load another file in libROSA?

Tags: python-3.x, librosa

I am new to LibROSA and wanted to know how to load a file which is not the default?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [load](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.load.html#librosa-core-load). Just provide the path to the file you want to load.